# How to elaborate with dependent records present?

Tags: dependent-type, implementation

Dependent records can be implemented in various ways, but some papers suggests I could do it in the following way:

- The construction of dependent record type is made by selecting labels and types.
- The construction of dependent record is made by filling up the fields.
- The destruction is made by selecting a label.

Eg. We could therefore do something like: `sig : {fst: A, snd: B fst}` to represent sigma. Then construct it with `sig = {fst=a, snd=b}`, and retrieve the second field with `sig.snd`.

But now I hit elaboration phase where the input program is turned into bunch of constraints. This means I do not necessarily have information about the record type before I resolve record fields. With the naive elaborator I have no information about types during elaboration.

Specifically for inference. Given some `(a:_)` with type yet undetermined and then label `a.snd`. Which type should I give when I cannot know the specific record? What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1. Complain that not enough typing information has been given, the same way that you would complain if the input is just a bare `λ x → x`. Bidirectional type checking is good at doing that.
2. Require that all record types be defined in advance. For a simple life, you disallow reuse of field names so that upon seeing a field name you know which type it belongs to. For a more interesting life you disambiguate field names when possible.
3. You walk into the bogs of [record subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Record_types). This is a radical move that has to be carefully combined with the rest of your type theory.
4. You might be able to use [row polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_polymorphism), although that seems to work only for non-dependent record types. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I decided to look into the bog and found a few subtyping papers for records. Including this one: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263162385_A_Theory_of_Dependent_Record_Types_with_Structural_Subtyping

Comment: I spoke too soon, that paper is not helping me much.

Comment: What are you doing? What's the larger problem you're solving?

Comment: I addded a fourth possibility.

Comment: I saw a paper "Eliminating the problems of hidden-lambda insertion" www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/MScThesisJohanssonLloyd.pdf and decided to implement implicit arguments as a record attached to every lambda. Broader answer: trying to implement my own dependently typed language.

Comment: Uhm, doesn't that thesis give a type checking procedure?

Comment: @Cheery that source is significantly improved upon by: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3408983 Which in turn, IMO, is practically obsoleted by https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/elaboration-zoo/tree/master/06-first-class-poly